# detect binary data in string

Tags: php, string, text, binary

Huh, another question about PHP. Let's say I have some string containing data from remote url that I've read using `readfile` and output buffer. Now, I do not know if it's some text file (i.e. HTML or CSS) or binary file (i.e. image or video). How can I distinguish what's stored in such created variable (`$out1`)?

```
    ob_start();
    $filesize = readfile($url);
    $out1 = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: header content type ?

Comment: I checked on a few random addresses and in some cases content type is not provided within headers. Even if it is: how can I read headers with readfile? Should I switch to curl instead?

Comment: Ultimately you cannot. Something which may look like binary gibberish may just be a really unusual text encoding. It's all just bytes. You should heed the header information and/or *know* what you're expecting.

Comment: The trick is that I do not know what to expect since the script will get some random parameter with address and furthermore in case of HTML/CSS scan for additional resources to fetch them as well... so the question is: how can I check response headers from PHP level (for now I will simply assume that without content-type it's binary)

Comment: curl is mandatory ( i think ) in this case, you can't guess the content type, this information must be provided by the owner of file that you try to get/read/download... the only thing that you can do is to set a default content type it it's missed from header...

Comment: `$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);`

Comment: Better would be $response_content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);